# CSS child element does not inherit parent height

Tags: html, css, height, overflow

I want to make some sort of modal box so that parent box will be always smaller than window size but child box may have any height and should have scroll bar if it's height bigger than parent's height.

So, I tried to make this but child element does not inherit parent's height (despite that child height is set to 100%) and I can't apply `overflow-y: auto` property to the child element for scrolling. This property works only for parent element otherwise child overlaps parent.

How to prevent child element to overlap parent?

[image]

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
}
.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
.parent {
  min-width: 200px;
  max-width: 300px;
  min-height: 200px;
  max-height: 80%;
  background-color: red;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 20px;
  /* overflow-y: auto; */ /* works! */
  
}
.child {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%; /* assumes parents height */
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  overflow-y: hidden; /* doesn't work! */
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="parent">
    <div class="child">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Vero sapiente voluptatem adipisci ex, cum odio deserunt magnam obcaecati incidunt, nemo ipsum corrupti ratione laudantium reprehenderit mollitia ut, eligendi commodi, id!
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Vero sapiente voluptatem adipisci ex, cum odio deserunt magnam obcaecati incidunt, nemo ipsum corrupti ratione laudantium reprehenderit mollitia ut, eligendi commodi, id!
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Vero sapiente voluptatem adipisci ex, cum odio deserunt magnam obcaecati incidunt, nemo ipsum corrupti ratione laudantium reprehenderit mollitia ut, eligendi commodi, id!
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Vero sapiente voluptatem adipisci ex, cum odio deserunt magnam obcaecati incidunt, nemo ipsum corrupti ratione laudantium reprehenderit mollitia ut, eligendi commodi, id!
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Vero sapiente voluptatem adipisci ex, cum odio deserunt magnam obcaecati incidunt, nemo ipsum corrupti ratione laudantium reprehenderit mollitia ut, eligendi commodi, id!
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Vero sapiente voluptatem adipisci ex, cum odio deserunt magnam obcaecati incidunt, nemo ipsum corrupti ratione laudantium reprehenderit mollitia ut, eligendi commodi, id!
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Vero sapiente voluptatem adipisci ex, cum odio deserunt magnam obcaecati incidunt, nemo ipsum corrupti ratione laudantium reprehenderit mollitia ut, eligendi commodi, id!
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Vero sapiente voluptatem adipisci ex, cum odio deserunt magnam obcaecati incidunt, nemo ipsum corrupti ratione laudantium reprehenderit mollitia ut, eligendi commodi, id!
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Vero sapiente voluptatem adipisci ex, cum odio deserunt magnam obcaecati incidunt, nemo ipsum corrupti ratione laudantium reprehenderit mollitia ut, eligendi commodi, id!
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Vero sapiente voluptatem adipisci ex, cum odio deserunt magnam obcaecati incidunt, nemo ipsum corrupti ratione laudantium reprehenderit mollitia ut, eligendi commodi, id!
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Vero sapiente voluptatem adipisci ex, cum odio deserunt magnam obcaecati incidunt, nemo ipsum corrupti ratione laudantium reprehenderit mollitia ut, eligendi commodi, id!
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Vero sapiente voluptatem adipisci ex, cum odio deserunt magnam obcaecati incidunt, nemo ipsum corrupti ratione laudantium reprehenderit mollitia ut, eligendi commodi, id!
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Vero sapiente voluptatem adipisci ex, cum odio deserunt magnam obcaecati incidunt, nemo ipsum corrupti ratione laudantium reprehenderit mollitia ut, eligendi commodi, id!
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Vero sapiente voluptatem adipisci ex, cum odio deserunt magnam obcaecati incidunt, nemo ipsum corrupti ratione laudantium reprehenderit mollitia ut, eligendi commodi, id!
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Vero sapiente voluptatem adipisci ex, cum odio deserunt magnam obcaecati incidunt, nemo ipsum corrupti ratione laudantium reprehenderit mollitia ut, eligendi commodi, id!
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Vero sapiente voluptatem adipisci ex, cum odio deserunt magnam obcaecati incidunt, nemo ipsum corrupti ratione laudantium reprehenderit mollitia ut, eligendi commodi, id!
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Vero sapiente voluptatem adipisci ex, cum odio deserunt magnam obcaecati incidunt, nemo ipsum corrupti ratione laudantium reprehenderit mollitia ut, eligendi commodi, id!
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Vero sapiente voluptatem adipisci ex, cum odio deserunt magnam obcaecati incidunt, nemo ipsum corrupti ratione laudantium reprehenderit mollitia ut, eligendi commodi, id!
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: because you set max-height and not height

Comment: read this one : https://stackoverflow.com/a/31728799/8620333 (until the end)

Comment: @TemaniAfif, thanks, but I can't find a solution for this issue yet. If I set height for the parent element it would not be resizable with its child content.

Comment: why not simply using overflow on parent like you already did? this is the logical way to prevent the overfow

Comment: @TemaniAfif, I thought about it, but then every helper element will be hidden, e.i. if I want to add close button to the parent element. So, this approach is a crutch rather than solution.

Comment: then apply the same logic on the child element, add max-height to it also and it will behave the same as his parent. but use `vh` unit for both so make both of them `max-height:80vh` or less for the child element to keep some space for your buttons

Comment: No, this doesn't work. As you mentioned link before absolute positioning solves the problem for the child element. Still more like a crutch.

Comment: it does work, check this : https://jsfiddle.net/jn1mk2bx/ no need absolute element, simply use `vh` unit

Comment: a more accurate code with centring and everything: https://jsfiddle.net/jn1mk2bx/1/

Answer (score 0):

remove `max-height` of the parent. thanks

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
}
.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
.parent {
  min-width: 200px;
  max-width: 300px;
  min-height: 200px;
  background-color: red;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 20px;
  /* overflow-y: auto; */ /* works! */
}
.child {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%; /* assumes parents height */
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  overflow-y: hidden; /* doesn't work! */
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="parent">
    <div class="child">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Vero sapiente voluptatem adipisci ex, cum odio deserunt magnam obcaecati incidunt, nemo ipsum corrupti ratione laudantium reprehenderit mollitia ut, eligendi commodi, id!
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Vero sapiente voluptatem adipisci ex, cum odio deserunt magnam obcaecati incidunt, nemo ipsum corrupti ratione laudantium reprehenderit mollitia ut, eligendi commodi, id!
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Vero sapiente voluptatem adipisci ex, cum odio deserunt magnam obcaecati incidunt, nemo ipsum corrupti ratione laudantium reprehenderit mollitia ut, eligendi commodi, id!
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Vero sapiente voluptatem adipisci ex, cum odio deserunt magnam obcaecati incidunt, nemo ipsum corrupti ratione laudantium reprehenderit mollitia ut, eligendi commodi, id!
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Vero sapiente voluptatem adipisci ex, cum odio deserunt magnam obcaecati incidunt, nemo ipsum corrupti ratione laudantium reprehenderit mollitia ut, eligendi commodi, id!
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Vero sapiente voluptatem adipisci ex, cum odio deserunt magnam obcaecati incidunt, nemo ipsum corrupti ratione laudantium reprehenderit mollitia ut, eligendi commodi, id!
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Vero sapiente voluptatem adipisci ex, cum odio deserunt magnam obcaecati incidunt, nemo ipsum corrupti ratione laudantium reprehenderit mollitia ut, eligendi commodi, id!
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Vero sapiente voluptatem adipisci ex, cum odio deserunt magnam obcaecati incidunt, nemo ipsum corrupti ratione laudantium reprehenderit mollitia ut, eligendi commodi, id!
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Vero sapiente voluptatem adipisci ex, cum odio deserunt magnam obcaecati incidunt, nemo ipsum corrupti ratione laudantium reprehenderit mollitia ut, eligendi commodi, id!
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Vero sapiente voluptatem adipisci ex, cum odio deserunt magnam obcaecati incidunt, nemo ipsum corrupti ratione laudantium reprehenderit mollitia ut, eligendi commodi, id!
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Vero sapiente voluptatem adipisci ex, cum odio deserunt magnam obcaecati incidunt, nemo ipsum corrupti ratione laudantium reprehenderit mollitia ut, eligendi commodi, id!
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Vero sapiente voluptatem adipisci ex, cum odio deserunt magnam obcaecati incidunt, nemo ipsum corrupti ratione laudantium reprehenderit mollitia ut, eligendi commodi, id!
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Vero sapiente voluptatem adipisci ex, cum odio deserunt magnam obcaecati incidunt, nemo ipsum corrupti ratione laudantium reprehenderit mollitia ut, eligendi commodi, id!
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Vero sapiente voluptatem adipisci ex, cum odio deserunt magnam obcaecati incidunt, nemo ipsum corrupti ratione laudantium reprehenderit mollitia ut, eligendi commodi, id!
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Vero sapiente voluptatem adipisci ex, cum odio deserunt magnam obcaecati incidunt, nemo ipsum corrupti ratione laudantium reprehenderit mollitia ut, eligendi commodi, id!
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Vero sapiente voluptatem adipisci ex, cum odio deserunt magnam obcaecati incidunt, nemo ipsum corrupti ratione laudantium reprehenderit mollitia ut, eligendi commodi, id!
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Vero sapiente voluptatem adipisci ex, cum odio deserunt magnam obcaecati incidunt, nemo ipsum corrupti ratione laudantium reprehenderit mollitia ut, eligendi commodi, id!
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Vero sapiente voluptatem adipisci ex, cum odio deserunt magnam obcaecati incidunt, nemo ipsum corrupti ratione laudantium reprehenderit mollitia ut, eligendi commodi, id!
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Remove `max-height: 80%;` from `.parent`

Comment: Parent element should be resizable related to it's child content.

Comment: remove max-width add width with % in .parent and it will be resizable